# Sorting a table by one column in R

Tags: mysql, r, sorting, dataframe

I have this table:

```
head(tb)
    shot_made_flag
opponent        0        1
    ATL 54.79452 45.20548
    BKN 60.00000 40.00000
    BOS 58.87612 41.12388
    CHA 56.40000 43.60000
    CHI 56.97674 43.02326
    CLE 56.03113 43.96887
```

And this is my code:

```
table(opponent,shot_made_flag)
rowSums(table(opponent,shot_made_flag))
b<table(opponent,shot_made_flag)/rowSums(table(opponent,shot_made_flag))*100
head(tb)
```

I would like to sort my table by values in column 1, but I never get the table back as a result. I only get the values in column 1 sorted in crescent (or decrescent order)

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the `data`.  Is it a `table` object?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to execute the MySQL query?  What package are you using?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `order` function and a `-` (minus) sign before the column to be arranged in descending order and no minus sign if you want the `Result` in ascending order.

```
   df <- read.table(header=T, text="
   opponent        0        1
   ATL 54.79452 45.20548
   BKN 60.00000 40.00000
   BOS 58.87612 41.12388
   CHA 56.40000 43.60000
   CHI 56.97674 43.02326
   CLE 56.03113 43.96887
   ",check.names=F)

   df
   #   opponent        0        1
   # 1      ATL 54.79452 45.20548
   # 2      BKN 60.00000 40.00000
   # 3      BOS 58.87612 41.12388
   # 4      CHA 56.40000 43.60000
   # 5      CHI 56.97674 43.02326
   # 6      CLE 56.03113 43.96887

   names(df)
   # [1] "opponent"  "0"       "1"      

   Result <- df[order(-df$"1"),]
   Result
   #   opponent        0        1
   # 1      ATL 54.79452 45.20548
   # 6      CLE 56.03113 43.96887
   # 4      CHA 56.40000 43.60000
   # 5      CHI 56.97674 43.02326
   # 3      BOS 58.87612 41.12388
   # 2      BKN 60.00000 40.00000

   # Alternative
   Result <- df[order(-df[,3]),]
   Result
   #   opponent        0        1
   # 1      ATL 54.79452 45.20548
   # 6      CLE 56.03113 43.96887
   # 4      CHA 56.40000 43.60000
   # 5      CHI 56.97674 43.02326
   # 3      BOS 58.87612 41.12388
   # 2      BKN 60.00000 40.00000
```